# Create blank Shapefile in C#

Tags: shapefile, c#

I just want to create a Blank Shapefile using c#. 
Any one suggest me code for it?

Comment: Welcome to GSE. Please update the question to include enough detail to make it answerable. You should include more details about your development environment (OS, compiler, code library version) and details of what you have tried so far. You should probably define "blank shapefile", since no such thing exists. If you don’t demonstrate effort in the question, it's unlikely that you will receive an answer.

Comment: How about trying the [esri whitepaper on the shapefile technical description](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf)?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nettopologysuite/AKSteVpqtfY) might be your question, too.  They are very similar.

The suggested code answer there is:

```
ShapefileDataWriter writer = new ShapefileDataWriter(filename, Factory);
writer.Header = new DbaseFileHeader();
writer.Write(new IFeature[0]);
```

Credit goes to the person who answered this in the other form.  I am just citing it to help complete this one.